# Dual Boot and Grub

Tags: grub2

This is my third question. 
I have installed Ubuntu on my PC now, but what i did when installing is i unplugged all my HDD's except for the one i wanted to install Ubuntu on.  (i wanted to be sure i wasnt erasing anything, at first i wanted to install with all the drives in, but the ubuntu installer is Vague when it comes to highlighting which drive i am actually installing to i found, you lot might disagree, so i shut down the install and unplugged all my drives except for the on i wanted to install on to)

So, i installed Ubuntu.  Turned off the PC, then i pluggged the other HDD back in to the PC and re-booted.

It loaded Ubuntu with out giving me the option to choose which OS.

So i went to Bios changed the boot to boot from my windows drive and here i am now asking...

How do i install Grub or get it to work after i have installed Ubuntu and re-plugged back in my Windows drive ?

Or am i dammed to have to switch the boot on bios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect all HDD's. Boot into Ubuntu. Open Terminal ( Ctrl+Alt+t ). In terminal type:`sudo update-grub`and fill in your password. Reboot. You will see GRUB-menu and be able to choose the OS you wish to boot.